# Golf game use visitor pattern, why is it a bad idea in this situation？

Tags: design-patterns, visitor-pattern

- You are writing a golf game, and you are trying to simulate a ball rolling from point to point in the golf course.
- Your partner suggests that you use the `Visitor pattern` since the ball “visits” each point.
- That way it can have different behavior for sand, a slight hill, the rough, a tree, water, etc.
- He likes the name `BallMovementVisitor`. Explain why this is a **bad idea**?

Comment: And what if it's not? Why do you think it's a bad idea if you can't explain it yourself?

Comment: It sounds like homework or an exam question. Is it?

Comment: Yes， it is a homework.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. It might be better suited for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good or bad is kind of a choice.

Personally, I don't like the idea of using visitor pattern here.

If we revisit a visitor example from [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/java/1), simply visitor pattern is directing a method call based on method overloading.

```
interface Visitor {
    void visit(FOO foo);
    void visit(BAR bar);
    void visit(BAZ baz);
}
```

If we use it for your example, the only convenient way, I can find is, use overloading based on different environment types. i.e.

- FOO => Sand
- Bar => SlightHill etc.

You can do your business with that way. But conversely there are some notable cons.

You need to keep adding different overloading methods inside your visitor interface/class when requirements are defined to add new environment types. If you look in perspective of [solid principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), you are violating OCP [it'a choice though, not a dogma. :) ].

A more decent approach for me is using either [strategy](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) or [command](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command) pattern.

Comment: Thank you. I think using state pattern is ok, yep?

Comment: @SditeVon If your objective is to track different environment type changes i.e. history/tracking, it does. In case of implementing different behaviors w.r.t. each environment, it doesn't make sense.